# Combining GDAL dataset tiles in C++

Tags: c++, gdal

I'm getting some prototype Python code that uses GDAL moved to C++ and I'm stuck on a section that reads tiles of elevation data from a directory and combines them into a single dataset. The Python code looks like:

```
# Read files containing elevation data in 1° x 1° squares.
geo_file_list = glob.glob ("./geodata/*.hgt")

# Turn the list of files into a list of datasets.
elv_dataset_list = list(map(gdal.Open, geo_file_list))

# Merge datasets into a single one.
elv_dataset = gdal.BuildVRT('', elv_dataset_list)
```

I'm never writing out the resulting VRT, only keeping it memory for further processing. I'd create a MEM driver and use that if possible.

In C++, I'm starting with:

```
// Set data directory.
std::string elev_dir = "./geodata/";

// Get list of files in data directory.
std::vector<GDALDataset *> elev_datasets;

// Read files into datasets.
for(auto& p: std::filesystem::directory_iterator(elev_dir)) {
    elev_datasets.push_back((GDALDataset *) GDALOpen (p.path().c_str(), GA_ReadOnly));
}
```

The part I'm struggling with is sending the resulting std::vector to GDALBuildVRT(). Very possible that I'm going about this all wrong!

Answer (score 0):

The trick was realizing that `nullptr` is an acceptable input into `GDALBuildVRT()` for arguments that should be ignored. Hence, the call looks like:

```
GDALDataset *dest_dataset = (GDALDataset *) GDALBuildVRT("", elev_datasets.size(), (GDALDatasetH *) elev_datasets.data(), nullptr, nullptr, nullptr);
```